# Pass non-localhost name for Kubernetes Python client

Tags: python, kubernetes

I wanted to know if the Kubernetes Python client API's have a provision where i can pass the hostname of interest instead of the API's having to use localhost.

TIA

Comment: I was running the python program from within the POD and had forgotten to load the inter cluster config. Once i added config.load_incluster_config(), things started working as expected.

Comment: you should put that in an answer, and mark it as accepted. This will make it easier for people in the future who have this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was running the python program from within the POD and had forgotten to load the inter cluster config. Once i added config.load_incluster_config(), things started working as expected